# Ruby: is this a metaprogramming proc call or custom method

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, proc

I was following the tutorial https://paweljw.github.io/2017/07/rails-5.1-api-app-part-4-authentication-and-authorization/ and I was confused by this:

```
  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def call
    @result = nil
    payload
    self
  end
```

I thought that self.call(*args) from a [proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html), yet call is defined in the very next line. So in this example, is the author using the proc or using his own defined call method?

Full code:

```
class BaseCommand
  attr_reader :result

  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def call
    @result = nil
    payload
    self
  end

  def success?
    errors.empty?
  end

  def errors
    @errors ||= ActiveModel::Errors.new(self)
  end

  private

  def initialize(*_)
    not_implemented
  end

  def payload
    not_implemented
  end
end

class DecodeAuthenticationCommand < BaseCommand
  private

  attr_reader :headers

  def initialize(headers)
    @headers = headers
    @user = nil
  end

  def payload
    return unless token_present?
    @result = user if user
  end

  def user
    @user ||= User.find_by(id: decoded_id)
    @user || errors.add(:token, I18n.t('decode_authentication_command.token_invalid')) && nil
  end

  def token_present?
    token.present? && token_contents.present?
  end

  def token
    return authorization_header.split(' ').last if authorization_header.present?
    errors.add(:token, I18n.t('decode_authentication_command.token_missing'))
    nil
  end

  def authorization_header
    headers['Authorization']
  end

  def token_contents
    @token_contents ||= begin
      decoded = JwtService.decode(token)
      errors.add(:token, I18n.t('decode_authentication_command.token_expired')) unless decoded
      decoded
    end
  end

  def decoded_id
    token_contents['user_id']
  end
end
```

Comment: The code posted does not make much sense, since neither `payload` nor `not_implemented` are declared and it in general looks like a scaffold for the future. Also, there is no metaprogramming involved in the code above.

Comment: `BaseCommand` is just a class, so both `self.call` and `call` are custom defined methods - _class_ and _instance_ respectively.

Comment: @mudasobwa I added the code that references this class

Comment: The `self.call` method above allows you to write `BaseCommand.call(:foo)` instead of `BaseCommand.new.call(foo)` – it's a shortcut.